# illegalaccesserror SEEK for Android

Tags: android, seek

i am building an app based on SEEK for Android.
I am facing 
    `illegalaccesserror`
 every time i run the application with `<uses-library android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi"/>` 
Any pointers will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all never mind the issue was occurred due to library configuration.

Thanks... :)